# Make a quarter circular ring with 1 div

Tags: html, css, mask, clip

I have created a quarter ring using the following code

```
        .quarter {
            position:absolute;
            width:50%;
            height:50%;
            transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
        }
        .quarter1 {
            top:0;
            left:0;
            border-radius:100% 0 0 0;
        }
        .main-container {
           height: 200px;
           width: 200px
        }

        .cutout {
          width:50%;
          height:50%;
          background-color:white;
          position:absolute;
          top:25%;
          left:25%;
          border-radius:50%;
          pointer-events:none;
      }
```

HTML CODE

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="quarter quarter1"></div>
  <div class="cutout"></div>
</div>
```

This creates the following
[image]

I would like to know if it's possible to do the above using just 1 div and the mask/clipping properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do it with radial gradients.

```css
.quarter_ring {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 100% 100%, transparent 0%, transparent 40%, red 41%, Red 70%, transparent 71%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class='quarter_ring'></div>
```